# How do I open a URL on the client machine using java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying to open a static url from a web application when user clicks a button on a screen. Our application is deployed on a linux box and using the below program its trying to open a browser. Can you please advise how I can get it to to open it on the client instead ?

All our users access this application from windows.

```
try {
          Desktop desktop = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop();
          URI oURL = new URI("http://www.google.com");
          desktop.browse(oURL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Did I get this right, you want to open a program on a client by some code running on the server?

Comment: Just in case it was not obvious - @Henry is pointing out that what you're trying to do is really unlikely to work, absent a boatload of machinery.  If you want the client's browser to open a new page, the code to do that has to be executed by the client browser.   If the server controls which page to open, the client browser would need an Ajax call to ask the server which page to open, and the client would then open a new window on that URL using Javascript API (something like window.open() ?)

Comment: sorry for not being clear. Yep, our web application is deployed on weblogic on a linux box and users access this application from windows and we want this program to launch a browser on the client machine on click of a button.

Comment: Is this button on a web page that is open in the user's browser? Also a tip: Add @moilejter (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Well - the simplest answer would be to have the button be part of a form that sends a request to the server when you click it, so that the server can then reply to that form submission with a redirect to the page that the server wants the user to see.  If you actually want the click to open a second window, then you would prob have to associate that button click with an Ajax call, to ask the server what page to open, with an event handler than will call window.open() on success, to cause the browser to open that URL on a new window...

Answer (score -1):

I'm 99% sure above solution works only for windows, for unix I believe you should try something like this:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
runtime.exec("/usr/bin/firefox -new-window " + url);
```

Comment: Sorry I had to mention that all users access the application on Windows.

Comment: Would u please share more details about the server/client design and what you expect.

Comment: *"I'm 99% sure above solution works only for windows.."* You're 100% wrong. OTOH what the OP (and you) are attempting on the server side produces the wrong effect. Whether you consider it 100% working or 100% failing, 99% is still wrong. That's also a very fragile implementation of `exec`.  See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. ..

Comment: sorry for not being clear. Yep, our web application is deployed on weblogic on a linux box and users access this application from windows and we want this program to launch a browser on the client machine on click of a button.

Comment: .. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.

Comment: When you said `launch a browser on the client machine on click of a button.`  you're referring the button to either your web application deployed on weblogic or shortcut button  ?